# EV3 additional build instructions - PDF download or print possible?

Tags: mindstorms, instructions, ev3

The EV3 retail edition comes with printed instructions to build only one of the possible robots and it appears you have to use the software to view the build instructions of the other models.

My question is: is it possible to download or export/print these additional model instructions?

I have attempted to find both downloads (Lego's PDF search function returns nothing) and an export/print option to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit to add:

PDF downloads are now available from the LEGO Site:

> [3D Building Instructions](http://www.us.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/community/bi/)

---

The images used for building instructions are available (jpeg images) in folder `C:\Program Files\LEGO Software\LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition\Resources\ContentPacks\Retail\nonlocalized\LEGO\pack0\projects` (more or less, depends on OS and installation choices). **Take care not to modify anything there, as you might need to reinstall the software!**

It's a bit more complex for .ev3 project files containing building instructions (eg. downloadable bonus models):

1. Open the ev3 project file as if it is a zip archive.
2. Inside you'll find a file named ActivityAssets.laz. Open this one as
   a zip archive too,
3. it contains all the images for building instructions. You can
   extract those images to a separate location
4. then you can print those images or build a PDFfile, you can put that on your tablet...
5. take care not to modify the project files!

**Remember that these images are the property of their owner (LEGO or model builder), use them for you own personal needs only!**

Comment: Thanks - seems like the only option until/if Lego release the manuals as PDF downloads.

Comment: Building instructions of 31313 retail set official models are now available: http://www.us.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/community/bi/